# Intellisense desaparece quando a lista de argumentos é grande

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2010 percebi que quando a lista de parâmetros do construtor é muito grande e não cabe na tela o Visual Studio não exibe mais a lista de parâmetros do construtor. É possível configurá-lo para que exiba todos sem distinção?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é uma boa prática utilizar uma lista de argumentos muito grande, seu código fica difícil de dar manutenção. Já pensou em passar um objeto mais simples contendo as propriedades que você quer definir no seu construtor e então trata-las no construtor em vez de uma lista imensa de argumentos? Mas é só uma sugestão.

Comment: @GabrielGartz mas ele está passando dados de pessoa.. criar outra classe só para passar... uma pessoa como parâmetro da outra? Até usando DTO isso fica estranho :p

Comment: Faz um tempo que eu não uso dotNet. Quando eu usava eu tinha o [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) no meu Visual Studio, ele faz muitas melhorias na ide. Agora eu honestamente não sei se ele resolve este seu problema, você pode dar uma olhada [neste link](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion.html) e ver se tem algo que resolve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma solução seria ter um contrutor simples e usar a sintaxe de inicializadores de propriedades que veio com o .NET 3.0

Seu código teria um construtor vazio ou com apenas um ou dois parâmetros e as outras propriedades seriam inicializadas em separado durante a contrução:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa() {
    Nome = "nome",
    Sobrenome = "sobrenome",
    Idade = 33,
    Profissao = "programador",
    Salario = 10000.50,
    DtNascimento = new DateTime(12,12,1912)
};
```

Desta forma o Intellisense vai completar todas as propriedades inicializáveis dentro das chaves e quando põe vírgula e o programador pode inicializar quantas quiser sem precisar passar nulo ou string vazia para aqueles parametros que não tem no momento.

Comment: +1. Se `Pessoa` é apenas um model com properties eu concordo que o construtor não deveria receber nada já que nenhuma ação é executada nos "setters".

Comment: Mas mesmo que tenha setters, as ações deveriam estar no set das propriedades (que devem ter get e set devidamente validados e tudo mais). Acaba podendo ser usada em outras situações também.

Answer (score 3):

A principio, não. Uma possível solução seria testar se o Visual Studio 2013.

Esse é um tipo de erro que se fosse possível resolver sem perguntar ao usuário, deveriam fazer por padrão. O irritante nele é que isso pode causar falso positivo e achar que a função só tem isso mesmo de parâmetro.

Algo que vi é que tinha plugins que pareciam melhorar o Intellisense para outras coisas e provavelmente também deveriam resolver isso, e talvez isso resolva se esse erro realmente for irritante a você.

Fonte: uns dois anos atrás também tive que usar o Visual Studio 2010 e passei exatamente pelo menos problema e também por lentidão em certos projetos. Na época eu achei que era um bug, e lembro de ter procurado mas não achei referência alguma sobre isso.

Comment: Emerson uma coisa que notei é que se você deixar um espaço maior(der um scroll no código) ele volta a aparecer.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa seria escolher uma fonte diferente ou reduzir seu tamanho através do menu

`Ferramentas-> Opções-> Ambiente-> Fontes e cores`

E escolhendo `Dica de ferramenta do Editor` no menu *drop-down* para fazer as alterações.